# selenium doesnt display all of webpage

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am working on a scraper that will search through an employee's page on bluepages (an internal IBM website), and get employee name, department, and download a copy of their resume. unfortunately, when i run open the web-page with selenium, it only loads the top part of the page, and nothing else. I have tried switching into Iframes, as well as waiting for elements to load. when opening the site in Firefox, all parts of the page open up immediately, and don't require a button press.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What browser are you using in selenium? Could it be an issue with the size of the window? If so you could tell the `driver` to maximize the window first thing before hitting your site. Things should load in the browser the same way for a driver as they would without selenium, unless there is some plugin or something you don't have enabled in your `driver` that the site you're looking at depends on.

Comment: Im using PhantomJS, I cant use chrome, or safari, and geckodriver for firefox uses permissions i dont have.

Comment: What is the selenium version and phantomjs version?

Comment: selenium version = 3.4.3
phantomjs verison = 2.1.1